# Can I install multiple database management systems on a same machine having ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: postgresql, database, mariadb

I currently have **Postgresql** installed on my system but I also want to install **mariadb** on my system. So I want to know is that okay or it will show errors after installing mariadb.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you install different DBMS correctly, no general issues should be expected. But there could be specific issues bound with wrong configuration. If you want to install different versions of the same DBMS, then it is better to investigate and use `docker` for this purpose. But even now you could use it if you're afraid of something could be wrong with mariadb installation on your current system.